# Patron Strategy

Tags: php, mvc, patrones-de-diseño, buenas-prácticas, interface

les paso a comentar, estoy queriendo validar unos campos y para esto decidi usar el patron strategy, asi que me dispuse a crear 2 interfaces una para checkear los valores del login

```
<?php
interface IvalidatorLogin {
    public function validate_username($username);
    public function validate_password($password);
    public function response($username, $password,$email,$is_admin,$status);
}
```

como veran el metodo **response** lleva mas argumentos que los que necesita, ya que lo que busco es reutilizar  **username** y **passsword** para validar tambien el registro de una cuenta nueva, la cual comparte estos parametros.

```
<?php
interface IvalidatorRegister {
    public function validate_email($email);
    public function validate_admin($is_admin);
    public function validate_status($status);
    public function response($username, $password,$email,$is_admin,$status);
}
```

En las implementaciones tengo lo siguiente para el **ValidatorLogin**

```
<?php
    class ValidatorLogin implements IvalidatorLogin{
        protected $username;
        protected $password;

        public function response($username, $password, $email, $is_admin, $status){
            $username = $this->validate_username($username);
            $password = $this->validate_password($password);

            return $username && $password ? true : false;
        }

        public function validate_username($username){
            if (isset($username) && !empty($username) && $username !== '') {
                if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ ]+$/', $username)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function validate_password($password){
            if (isset($password) && !empty($password) && $password !== '') {
                if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ ]+$/', $password)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

El validatorRegister queda de esta manera

```
<?php
class ValidatorRegister implements IvalidatorRegister,IvalidatorLogin
{
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $email;
    protected $is_admin;
    protected $status;

    public function response($username, $password,$email,$is_admin,$status)
    {
        $username = $this->validate_username($username);
        $password = $this->validate_password($password);
        $email = $this->validate_email($email);
        $is_admin = $this->validate_admin($is_admin);
        $status = $this->validate_status($status);
        return $username && $password && $email && $is_admin && $status ? true : false;
    }

    public function validate_username($username)
    {
        if (isset($username) && !empty($username) && $username !== '') {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ ]+$/', $username)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function validate_password($password)
    {
        if (isset($password) && !empty($password) && $password !== '') {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑ ]+$/', $password)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function validate_email($email)
    {
        if (isset($email) && !empty($email) && $email !== '') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function validate_admin($is_admin)
    {
        if($is_admin == 1 || $is_admin == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function validate_status($status){
        if($status == 1 || $status == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

El contexto quedo asi:

```
<?php
    class Validator {
        public $estrategia;

        public function __construct($estrategia)
        {
           $this->estrategia = $estrategia;
            //$this->password = $password;
        }
        public function setEstrategia($estrategia){

            $this->estrategia = $estrategia;


        }

        public function ejecutar ($username,$password,$email = null,$is_admin = null, $status = null){
            return $this->estrategia->response($username,$password,$email,$is_admin,$status);
        }
    }
```

Lo que me hace ruido es que en el contexto **validator** tenga que dejar por default los argumentos que en el login no uso. y que en el metodo de la interfaz **IvalidatoLogin** tenga que declarar argumentos que no voy a usar.Estoy incursionando en estas practicas de los patrones de diseño y cualquier critica constructiva que pueda mejorar el codigo me serviria muchisimo.Saludos!